# JavaFx TabPane style on click

Tags: java, swing, javafx, tabs

I used to develop my application in Swing. But recently I have begun to use JavaFx.

In Swing JTabPane we have this:

[image: JTabPane style in Swing]]

In JavaFx TabPane we have this:

[image: TabPane style in JavaFx]

We can see the selected Tab bigger than the other
But in JavaFx, we don't have this effect.

**Question**: How can I obtain the same Swing Tab style in JavaFx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve.

We can use CSS to make this style (Background-color, padding, :selected...)

Sorry I'm a beginner in JavaFx.